# Ethical question regarding authorship on CV

Tags: publications, ethics, cv, research-undergraduate

I am an undergraduate student doing research work for multiple PIs as part of an international particle physics collaboration. Although my work is related to recent papers published under this collaboration, I did not participate in the review or composition of these papers.

Is there an ethical way to list these papers on my CV to apply for summer research opportunities?

---

**Background**

Participating in collaborations at CERN may qualify you to enter the author list for a certain experiment, according to the minimum requirements stated by CERN. So you can get co-authorship on all papers published under the collaboration for a fixed period of time.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "my work is related"?
Did you contribute? Did you create data or perform experiments that are used in this paper?

Comment: I did not create data or prepare experiments for all of them, but some are more related than others. Let me be a little more specific - I am performing silicon sensor tests for an upgrade to one of the projects at CERN, so some relevant data was produced and processed by me, but not all papers published by my collaboration are directly relevant to anything I've contributed to, and I don't know if I could be considered a part of my collaboration as an undergrad.

Comment: If you haven't contributed to those papers. You cannot list them in your CV. 
However, you can use wordings like Buffy (see Answers) suggested. You participated in project "XYZ" led by Prof.X at CERN. (Assuming your work was part of a given "XYZ")

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would ask one or more of the professors whether something like the following would be ok with them.

> Participated in the "Undivided Underwater Basketweaving" project led by Prof X and Prof Y that resulted in the paper "...".

They might have better language that would be appropriate. If you were acknowledged by name in a paper you could say that as well.

Comment: Thanks, this helps. That's my main confusion - I don't know if I'm formally part of my collaboration, and my name is not listed under my institution on the author list, so I obviously can't say or imply that I am an author